# PM2 says executable is "errored" but isn't restarting it properly; need to still restart manually

Tags: node.js, mongodb, pm2

OK I know pm2 is meant primarily for managing nodejs apps, but it is convenient to use it also to manage some apps related to my project, in this case mongod.

When mongod crashes or becomes unresponsive, pm2 correctly sets its status to "errored" and I believe it tries to restart it "internally". The number of restarts increases to absurd numbers. Just that that automated restart doesn't recover mongod for some reason.

```
$ pm2 describe 0

Describing process with id 0 - name mongod 
┌───────────────────┬──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
│ status            │ errored                                              │
│ name              │ mongod                                               │
│ namespace         │ default                                              │
│ version           │ N/A                                                  │
│ restarts          │ 2931682                                              │
│ uptime            │ 0                                                    │
│ script path       │ /usr/bin/bash                                        │
│ script args       │ -c mongod --verbose --config /etc/mongod.conf --auth │
│ error log path    │ /root/.pm2/logs/mongod-error.log                     │
│ out log path      │ /root/.pm2/logs/mongod-out.log                       │
│ pid path          │ /root/.pm2/pids/mongod-0.pid                         │
│ interpreter       │ none                                                 │
│ interpreter args  │ N/A                                                  │
│ script id         │ 0                                                    │
│ exec cwd          │ /var/www/nodeapi                                     │
│ exec mode         │ fork_mode                                            │
│ node.js version   │ N/A                                                  │
│ node env          │ N/A                                                  │
│ watch & reload    │ ✘                                                    │
│ unstable restarts │ 0                                                    │
│ created at        │ N/A                                                  │
└───────────────────┴──────────────────────────────────────────────────────┘
```

When in this state, I can still successfully recover mongo using pm2 but only by issung the restart command manually:

```
$ pm2 restart 0
```

My first question is, what does the manual restart do that the automatic one doesn't? How come my manual restart succeeds in resurrecting mongod, but none of the automatic 2931682 restarts shown have succeeded?

Alternatively, perhaps mongod didn't crash at all, but pm2 just THINKS it crashed, and goes into a crazy restart loop.

So my second question is, how does pm2 decide whether an executable that is not nodejs, is crashed or not? Perhaps it infers from some heuristics in the log that it has crashed and makes the wrong classification calling it "errored"?

I do not understand how pm2 is in any position to judge the health of an app that isn't itself, especially if a shell script or binary 3rd-party executable. Any insights?

Answer (score 0):

I found that my mongo config file mandated mongod to be forked every which way it is started.

Also the mongo logs show an exit code of 48 which means it was unable to start due to the IP/port already being taken, ostensibly by another healthy mongod instance.

So pm2 kept restarting forever because, from a recent successful start, there was a mongod already running detached (forked) of which pm2 had no record of.

pm2 seems to expect anything it starts to be blocking until done. With the fork setting forced in the config, pm2 lost control of the process, and subsequent starts lead to the 48 exit code because, obviously, a prior forked mongod was already running.